# How to implement a screen unlock counter wherein it keeps counting even if we close the application?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have implemented the broadcast receiver and it counts the screen unlock events,but when i close the app it resets to 0.

I know that a service is required to be used but i don't know how it will update my variable in the Activity and keep it that way even if I close the application.

Following is the receiver.

Please help as I'm new to Android.

```
public class LockScreenStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MainActivity inst = MainActivity.instance();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // screen is turn off
            //("Screen locked");
        } else {
            //Handle resuming events if user is present/screen is unlocked
            inst.countUp();
            //("Screen unlocked");
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. : Also, is it possible to do something like this in Ionic Framework?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I used Shared Preferences for data saving and accessed them in the receiver as well.

Then to handle cases where the app is closed or just paused, I put some code in the try catch block.

However, I don't think this is a good way.
But it is  way in which I didn't had to use a Service.